# Rebuild widget when contents of list change

Tags: flutter, dart

I have objects in a list that users can remove. If the list is empty, I want to display some text but I tried to do this with a `ListView.builder()` and it displayed the text many times and I want it to be displayed just once. Is there some sort of property that I can listen to in the list?

Comment: How are you utilizing the `itemCount` property?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List items =new List();
  bool _isLoading =false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    items = getDummyList();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading=false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _isLoading
    ?Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      :
    items.length==0?Center(child: Text('No items in the list'),):
    Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Dismissible(
          key: Key(items[index]),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            setState(() {
              items.removeAt(index);
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 50.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1.0)),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  items[index],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )),
      ),
    );

  }

   List getDummyList(){
    setState(() {
      _isLoading=true;
    });
   List list =  List.generate(5, (i) {
    return "Item ${i +1 }";
    });
    return list;

  }
}
```

Check out this example , i have made a swipe dismiss example for listview,where if you remove the items it will display the text.

let me know if it works.

Thanks.